# Why does MinGW compiler/linker requires runtime library path to be properly set up?

Tags: windows, dll, mingw, dynamic-linking

I'm building a CMake project in Windows, using MSYS2/MinGW and VSCode, which includes both libraries and executables that link to them.
There no issues while building, however when attempting to run the executable I get "missing *.dll" errors as the shell because the required libraries can't be found by the system.

When I build the same code in a Linux machine, the required library paths are "baked" into the executable i.e. I can move it and execute from different paths ('ldd' lists the dependency's absolute path). Any particular reason why Windows behaves differently?

And more importantly, is there a way to solve this without adding custom project build locations to the PATH variable?

mingw-w64-x86_64-g++

Answer (score 1):

`.dll` and `.exe` files may depend on other `.dll` files.

If you run your `.exe` file it will look for the dependencies and fail to start if any of the dependency `.dll` files can't be found. It usually searches in the same folder as the .exe first, and if not found in the locations specified in the `PATH` environment variable.

So the cleanest solution is to copy dependencies to the same folder.

One tool that can do this is  `copedeps -r` from https://github.com/brechtsanders/pedeps
The `-r` is to copy recursively so you also get the `.dll` files `.dll` depend on etc...